# how to check textfield's previous value and modified value

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I'm new in iphone development.i want to give an alert message if `textfield's` text is whether change or not.how i can check textfield's text previous values and current values?

my code is

```
UITextField *txtCon;

NSString *strname;

txtCon.text = @"hello";

strname = txtCon.text;

if(txtCon.text == strname)
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rate on the Appstore!" 
                                                message:@"changed" 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Later" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
else
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rate on the Appstore!" 
                                                message:@"not changed" 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Later" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        if ([textField.text isEqualToString:strname])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rate on the Appstore!" 
                                                    message:@"changed" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Later" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];
       }
       else
       {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rate on the Appstore!" 
                                                    message:@"not changed" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Later" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
           [alert show];
          [alert release];
       }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastTextInTextField;
```

initialize it in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
self.lastTextInTextField = txtCon.text;
```

and then when your button gets pressed compare your retained textfield value to textfields string:

```
if ([self.lastTextInTextField isEqualToString:txtCon.text])
{
    // matches the old one;
}
else
{
    // not matched
}

// then just set this property value to current textfield string.
self.lastTextInTextField = txtCon.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(txtCon.text == strname)` this code is wrong you cant compare two string like this.
Right method is,

in .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString * oldValue;
    NSString * newValue;
}
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    oldvalue = txtCon.text;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{    
   newValue = txtCon.text
}

- (IBAction)yourBtn:(id)sender {    
   if ([oldvalue isEqualToString:newValue]) {
           //write your alert code here
    }else{
          //write your alert code here
          oldvalue =newValue;
    }
}
```

Otherwise your code looks nice.`textFieldDidEndEditing` called when textfield editing end at that time compare it with previous value if its not equal to than sat new value to the string.

I will recommend you to use your original textfield name instead of `textField` at this code `if ([txtCon.text isEqualToString:strname])`. becoz if you have more than one textfield than its better to use original name.

Comment: thanx for help..but i want to check that values is changed or not on button's clicked event..not on textfield's delegate.

Comment: than instead of `-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` write your button click event.

Comment: yeah,this is fine.but if i change any text in textfield,that text will going to store in straname..and this will not going to in else part.i want to store textfield previose value and thn modifield value..and than compare previous and current value.

Comment: So now when you first time click button oldVlue is nil and new value must be something so go in else part and newvlue will store in oldvalue. now if you click button second time without updating textfield value than oldvlue and newvalue will be same and if loop will execute.

Comment: @Dilip, You dont need two values for this thing, can do it using just one property, can check my answer buddy

Comment: @Bhupendra Yes, thats right but at that time i have this logic in mind. and two value does not harm anything so it will be fine.

Comment: @Dilip, yeah it wont harm, but code gets unnecessarily heavy and complicated, just this buddy, else everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {    

    if ([textField isEqual:txtCon])
    {
        // Code to get edited value of textfield
    }
}
```

this will help if there are lots of textfields ..